# Which libraries should go to a pkg-config file as a dependencies?

Tags: linux, cmake, g++, dynamic-linking, pkg-config

I'm writing a shared library that itself depends on `boost` and `pcl` libraries.

When generating `.pc` file for my library should I add all these libraries also to the `.pc` file as dependencies?

It's been a long time since I last time studied these things and I'm a bit confused how this worked again on Linux. When my test app links to my lib I have to add all these `pcl` and `boost` libs again to the build even though the lib already has been linked against these libs.

But when I look at the deps of `libQtGui.so`, for example, it has tens of all kinds of libs it links to, but I don't need to make my app link to those libs...only `-lQtGui` is enough.

I have just used CMake and `link_libraries` to add `boost` and `pcl` libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When generating .pc file for my library should I add all these libraries also to the .pc file as dependencies?

It depends on API of your library:

- if public (i.e. installable) headers of your lib use boost/pcl (i.e. have `#inclue <boost/...>`) (in other words you used `PUBLIC` (or `INTERFACE`) named keywords when link your library against boost/pcl in CMake+`target_link_libraries`) -- then *yes* you need to add 'em;
- otherwise, it depends on what exactly you have at the end -- i.e. does your DSO has `DT_NEEDED` entries for boost/pcl libs (most likely) or not (you can check it w/ `ldd <your-lib>.so`).  For the last case, you also need to add your dependencies to the `*.pc` files.

Also, in case of binary dependency from boost/pcl (dunno if the latter has any DSO or not) please make sure you specify exact location of the linked libs -- cuz a user may have multiple (co-existed) boost installations (potentially incompatible) or can do upgrade (later) to other (binary incompatible) version (and you can't really do smth w/ it)… It is important to be linked to the same (or at least binary compatible, which is kinda hard to guarantee for boost) library as you did…

> I have just used CMake and `link_libraries` to add boost and pcl libs.

Please read smth about "Modern CMake" and stop using `link_libraries` :-) -- use `target_link_libraries` instead…

Comment: Yeah, the reason for `link_libraries` is the fact I didn't write the CMakeLists.txt :p